# Add shortcut for JMenuItem in loop

Tags: java, keystroke, jmenu

I created my JMenu with specific categories and items inside. I want to add in for() shortcuts for each item depends on items count but I don't know how.

In for lopp I use this:

```
item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                    java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_x, 
                    java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK));
```

In 'x' I want to use numbers from 0-9 and if I have more items than 10 then change VK_x to VK_NUMPADx.

Is it possible is some easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int[] events = { KeyEvent.VK_0, KeyEvent.VK_1 ... KeyEvent.VK_9, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 ... KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9 };
JMenuItem[] items = {item1,item2 ... item20};
for(int i = 0;i < events.length && i < items.length;i++){
    items[i].setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                events[i], 
                Event.CTRL_MASK));
}
```

In this example, `item1` will be associated with `KeyEvent.VK_0`, `item2` with `KeyEvent.VK_1` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for help :) It works, in my case I prefer your way to do this.

Comment: @ullQuiorra I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

KeyEvent.VK_0 to KeyEvent.VK_9 are represented as decimal numbers 48 - 57 and KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 to KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9 are 106 - 115.

```
    int keyCode;
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.getItemCount(); i++) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
        if (i < 10) {
            keyCode = 48 + i;
        } else {
            keyCode = 106 + i % 10;
        }
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                keyCode,
                java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK));
    }
```

You can have in mind this idea also.